# Is it possible to query a many to many link and get a shallow set or array?

Tags: edgedb

Lets assume this simplified schema:

```
type default::Genre {
  required property name -> std::str {
    constraint std::exclusive;
  };
};

type default::Movie {
  required property title -> std::str;
  property year -> std::int64;
  multi link genres -> default::Genre;
};
```

When I query the movies like this:

```
select Movie {
  title,
  year,
  genres: {name}
}
limit 1
```

I get this response:

```
[
  {
    "title": "Troja",
    "year": 2004,
    "genres": [
      {
        "name": "Action"
      },
      {
        "name": "War"
      },
      {
        "name": "Adventure"
      },
      {
        "name": "History"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Is there a way to change the query to get this response instead

```
[
  {
    "title": "Troja",
    "year": 2004,
    "genres": [
      "Action", "War", "Adventure", "History"
    ]
  }
]
```

I looked through the documentation but I also don't what keyword to search for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now I figured out how to write the query to do this

```
SELECT Movie {
  title,
  year,
  genre_list := .genres.name
}
LIMIT 1
```

This will return a set, but the corresponding JSON will show a list:

```
[
  {
    "title": "Troja",
    "year": 2004,
    "genre_list": [
      "Action",
      "War",
      "Adventure",
      "History"
    ]
  }
]
```

If you really need an array instead you can use the [array_agg](https://www.edgedb.com/docs/stdlib/array#function::std::array_agg) function like this:

```
SELECT Movie {
  title,
  year,
  genre_list := array_agg(.genres.name)
}
LIMIT 1
```